# URL Rewrite is not working correctly in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to create a rewrite in my .htaccess file for my wordpress site.  I need 
www.a3performance.com/fastestsuit 
to point to 
http://www.a3performance.com/legend-fastest-racing-suit/

I am trying this, but it doesn't seem to work?

```
RewriteRule ^fastestsuit/?$ legend-fastest-racing-suit [NC,L]
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: The page is giving a 404 error

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need to use here Redirect from one folder to new folder.
Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /anotherdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Seems that the problem could be solved not by .htaccess but with the Permanent URL Settings in Wordpress.
Maybe you just need to change slugs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually @labris idea worked.  For some reason it took a bit for my server to register the .htaccess change.

```
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /anotherdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```